# WPF. Как загрузить и сохранить документ?

Tags: wpf, файлы

Необходимо вызвать окно диалога с 2-мя кнопками - "выбор файла" и "ок". Первая выберет файл (нужен PDF), вторая записывает этот файл в папку с проектом, как это реализовать?
И еще, как хранить эти файлы в БД? Хочу вносить туда строку с адресом... Спасибо

Comment: или хотя бы XpsDocument, если PDF сложно...

Comment: А в чём именно проблема?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Открытие файла: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/61097ykx(v=vs.110).aspx

Копирование файла в папку: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/c6cfw35a(v=vs.110).aspx

Если нужно копирование с возможностью перезаписи, советую посмотреть здесь: http://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/5.4.php